# How do I get PHP to work with UserDir

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I've got a fresh CentOS 5.5 box and have installed Webmin+VirtualMin 3.79. I've enabled UserDir in apache and the sites are visible via http://ipaddress/~user/ but PHP does not work. (PHP works fine if I visit the site via it's domain)

Here's what I put in my httpd.conf to get where I'm at:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
  Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  allow from all
  AllowOverride All
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
</Directory>
```

When I try to hit a PHP file, I get a 500 error and the following is logged to /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
suexec failure: could not open log file
fopen: Permission denied
```

Any help/direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Also make sure your php is using the right user within your apache(httpd) server on the given directory or it won't have access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use UserDir in this situation? The Apache developers discourage it in suexec environments, as there are security implications that can be hard to grok.

We have a FAQ about alternatives to UserDir (which also includes how to make UserDir work):

http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/faq